# Event Log slower read

Tags: c#, event-log

I have the problem with reading event log on remote machine, but i noticed Event Viewer read their faster
I tried 2 options for  read event log on remote machine

1. Option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--event-logs.
2. Option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.Reader.EventLogReader?view=net-5.0.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  Please add your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

need use class EventRecord and method ToXml()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).